# Find the limit of a given expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_{n})_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence with $a_{1} \geq 0$ and $a_{n + 1} = a_{n}(4 + a_{n})$, $n \geq 1$.

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2^{n}]{a_{n}}$

I have been trying to solve this exercise for a few days, but I got no answer. So please help me if you can.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to start by getting a closed form for $a_n$.

Comment: Unfortunately, at my highschool, I haven't learned how to derive a function yet.

Comment: Here are some good links to get you started. Also, it might help if you gave context for where you found the problem, how much of the prerequisite material you have covered already,etc. https://users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/alglectures/skiena.lectures/lecture3.pdf


http://db.math.ust.hk/notes_download/elementary/algebra/ae_A8.pdf


http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/LRGF.html

Comment: We have only covered the limits of sequences and no other analysis material.

Comment: Well you can start by observing that $a_{n+k}$ is a polynomial of degree $2^k$ in the variable $a_n$. You may actually prove this by induction. The general solution may well be beyond the scope of what you're doing as the limit changes drastically for different values of $a_1$. For example, $a_1 = .5$ gives that the limit is $\sqrt{2}$.